# Running python program in a silent mode

Tags: python, python-3.x

Usually, when I run a python program, I need to open a terminal and type things like

```
python program.py
```

But I want to run this python program without a terminal (or some window like that) running on Windows. But it will be running anyhow, just like Google Drive is always running on my PC without any windows being popped up. Is this possible? (I am making this program to run as soon as the Windows is booted up.)

Comment: on Windows you should have `pyw.exe` which run `.pyw` files without terminal.

Comment: @furas Thank you. I re-saved py file as pyw file and linked it to the pythonw.exe  And it does seem that it is running without terminal. But how do I know if the program is really running or not?

Comment: `pyw` is use mostly for programs with GUI and then you can see program window. If program use `print ` then people don't use `pyw`. If your program write to file you can see what is in file. But you can always run Program Manager and see what programs are running (I don't use WIndows and don't remember - Ctrl+Alt+Del or Ctrl+Shift+Esc)

Comment: If you run pythonw.exe on startup, then there should be a pythonw entry in TaskManager under processes.  It will not tell you which file it is running.  On Win10, at least, you can right click and try to attach a debugger, such as the one with VS 2015, and a debugger might be able to extract sys.argv.

Answer (score 1):

If on Linux, try:

```
python program.py &
```

Answer (score 0):

On windows there is an exe called sc.exe that would make services to run in the background.
Syntax looks like this:

```
sc [servername] create MYService binpath="c:\anaconda\bin\python.exe c:\scripts\myprog.py" start=auto
```

although I'm not sure if you have to put the binpath in quotes or just put that whole thing in a bat file and run that.